# Cannot save item to SharePoint list 2013

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Our SharePoint site with a list was working fine previously.

Suddenly, we are facing an issue while adding/updating list items. The NewForm/ EditForm page takes a long time to load and finally shows up an error page 'Unexpected Error Occurred'. But the list item gets saved. And the associated workflow is not getting triggered.

I tried to add/ update item from Quick Edit view and the same issue occurs.

When I tried to save the list as template and created a new list in the same site, the issue occurs in that list too.

But when I tried to do the same in some other environment it works fine for the list created from the above template.

We are not doing any customization and we don't have any server side code running.

User has full control access to the site and list.

This issue occurs after the recent patch upgrade to our SharePoint server.

Could use some one help.

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8axJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

****Fixed the issue.****

Started one service bus service in services, seemed to trigger the messaging side of things to start the workflow...but it's strange that would fix it since other workflows elsewhere were working.